# Can a client using JMS in springs receive messges from a server that implements JMS without springs?

Tags: java, jms

I need to implement JMS as part of RMI implementation.Which is better? using JMS with springs or without it?

Please explain the differences in these two or some references I can go through.

The client implementation is using Springs and the server implements simple RMI and JMS without using springs.

Will this communication work as expected or would there be any issues?

Can a client using JMS with springs receive messages from the server that implements JMS without springs?

Comment: What does 'implement JMS as part of RMI implementation' mean? JMS and RMI are completely distinct things. It doesn't appear to me that RMI has anything to do with this question.

Comment: I just mean that Iam implementing both and wanted to know if using springs is better in this issue?

Comment: You are implementing RMI? or you are implementing some services that are based on RMI?

Comment: @Galaxin 57% rate is a signal to go back through your questions and accept answers that you deem to be the best. This helps the community and people answering your questions appreciate the positive feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the client does not need to know anything about the server implementation.
You design your client they you want and whatever suites your needs and skills better.

JMS is just a message exchange protocol with many implementations. In my opinion Spring makes it easier to use. If you know grails, it will be even easier.

Good luck!